# Google Analytics Single Daily Report

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way to send a daily report with the current date's traffic only (not the whole month)? For example, if the report is sent 2015/01/25, I'd like to see traffic from 2015/01/25. I know I can manually select the data range but I'm looking for something that will automatically send daily PDF email report for current day only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Email* dialog of the *Custom Reporting* section, you can select a frequency of *Daily* and that will send your report every day for the previous day's data. Usually this is what you want since data for today will not always be current or accurate.

If you **really** need today's data, you can use the [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/) and set the value for the `start-date` and `end-date` parameters to `'today'`.

If you want to automate this process without too much effort, I'd recommend checking out the [Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2015/01/simplify-your-google-analytics.html), which uses the Core Reporting API behind the scenes. It won't email you reports, but you can do everything else you're asking.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'm gonna use the API.